# vertical bar on vector

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors, sparsity

I am reading a paper and I have problem to understand the equation ([this is the full paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7374282/))

> Assume that a one-dimensional discrete-time signal s of length N
> exhibits sparsity in certain orthonormal basis Ψ defined by the basis
> vectors $\Psi = [\Psi_{1}|\Psi_{2}|\Psi_{3}|...\Psi_{N}]$. Therefore, the signal s can be
> represented using its sparse transform domain vector x as follows:

What is the meaning of the vertical bar in $\Psi = [\Psi_{1}|\Psi_{2}|\Psi_{3}|...\Psi_{N}]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is:

> Assume that a one-dimensional discrete-time signal $s$ of length $N$ exhibits sparsity in certain orthonormal basis $\Psi$ defined by the basis vectors $\Psi=[\Psi_1∣\Psi_2∣\Psi_3∣\ldots\Psi_N]$.

So, it seems that $\Psi$ is an orthonormal basis, that the vectors of that basis are $\Psi_1,\Psi_2,\Psi_3,\ldots,\Psi_N$ and that $[\Psi_1∣\Psi_2∣\Psi_3∣\ldots\Psi_N]$ means $\{\Psi_1,\Psi_2,\Psi_3,\ldots,\Psi_N\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.